# Is it a good idea to use super() in Python?

Tags: python, oop, super

Or should I just explicitly reference the superclasses whose methods I want to call?

It seems brittle to repeat the names of super classes when referencing their constructors, but this page http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/ makes some good arguments against using super().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The book [Expert Python Programming](http://www.packtpub.com/expert-python-programming/) has discussed the topic of "super pitfalls" in chapter 3. It is worth reading. Below is the book's conclusion:

> Super usage has to be consistent: In a class hierarchy, super should be used everywhere or nowhere. Mixing super and classic calls is a confusing practice. People tend to avoid super, for their code to be more explicit.

**Edit:** Today I read this part of the book again. I'll copy some more sentences, since super usage is tricky:

- Avoid multiple inheritance in your code.
- Be consistent with its usage and don't mix new-style and
  old-style.
- Check the class hierarchy before calling its methods in
  your subclass.

Answer (score 6):

You can use super, but as the article says, there are drawbacks. As long as you know them, there is no problem with using the feature. It's like people saying "use composition, not inheritance" or "never use global variables". If the feature exists, there is a reason. Just be sure to understand the why and the what and use them wisely.

Comment: *"If the feature exists, there is a reason."* This argument is simply untrue. Many languages have features that should not be used by anyone ever.

Comment: @MikeGraham, ...eh, this is Chesterton's Fence. There's always a reason, but that doesn't mean that the reason remains relevant years later. Understanding the history behind a feature is relevant, though, to understanding what if any relevance remains.

Answer (score 5):

super() tries to solve for you the problem of multiple inheritance; it's hard to replicate its semantics and you certainly shouldn't create any new semantics unless you're completely sure.

For single inheritance, there's really no difference between

```
class X(Y):
    def func(self):
        Y.func(self)
```

and

```
class X(Y):
    def func(self):
        super().func()
```

so I guess that's just the question of taste.

Answer (score 3):

I like super()  more because it allows you to change the inherited class (for example when you're refactoring and add an intermediate class) without changing it on all the methods.

Comment: unless you're not using python 3 yet (which is the majority of python uses)

Comment: What do you mean? super() is on Python 2 too.

Comment: It's been backported I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem people have with `super` is more a problem of multiple inheritance. So it is a little unfair to blame `super`. Without `super` multiple inheritance is even worse. Michele Simionato nicely wrapped this up in his [blog article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=237121) on super:

> On the other hand, one may wonder if
>   all super warts aren't hints of some
>   serious problem underlying. It may
>   well be that the problem is not with
>   super, nor with cooperative methods:
>   the problem may be with multiple
>   inheritance itself.

So the main lesson is that you should try to avoid multiple inheritance.

In the interest of consistency I always use super, even if for single inheritance it does not really matter (apart from the small advantage of not having to know the parent class name). In Python 3+ `super` is more convenient, so there one should definitely use super.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `super()` over other methods. This is now the standard object inheritance model in Python 3.

Just stick to keyword arguments in your `__init__` methods and you shouldn't have too many problems. Additionally you can use `**kwargs` to support additional parameters that are not defined in levels of the inheritance chain.

I agree that it is brittle, but no less so than using the name of the inherited class.

Comment: You have written a good point. But would you consider making your answer a bit more verbose? `Yes` to which question? Question title `Is it a good idea to use super() in Python?`  or the first line of question `Or should I just explicitly reference the superclasses whose methods I want to call?` .   After reading your answer **multiple times** I think you have suggested to explicitly reference the superclasses instead of using super. But in my opinion, it is hard to understand your answer without reading it multiple times.

Comment: @Md.AbuNafeeIbnaZahid Added some extra wording. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. It is much better now.